# How to remove duplicate contact number from all type of contact without database?

Tags: android, contacts, android-contacts

How to remove duplicate number entry in Android when fetching contact number from contact book?

**For example:** 
In contact book for
    one    name multiple contact.. ex-type-home-9428060123,
    type-work-9428060123, I want to fetch unique contact number from all 
    type,android problematically? I use below code for fetching
    information:

```
private void getContactsDetails() {
 showLoader();
           String selection = ContactsContract.Contacts.IN_VISIBLE_GROUP + " = '"
                   + ("1") + "'";
           Cursor phones = getActivity().getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,
    null, null/*selection + " AND " +   
    ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER + "=1"*/, null, "UPPER("
    +    ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME + ") ASC");
           ContactString = new ArrayList<>();

           if (phones != null) {

               if (phones.getCount() > 0) {
                   tvNoContact.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                   while (phones.moveToNext()) {
                       String Name = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME));
                       String number = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
                  HashSet<String> mobileNoSet = new HashSet<String>();
                if (!mobileNoSet.contains(number)){
                       String s = number.replaceAll("\\W", "");
                       String lastTenCharContact = null;
                       if (s != null && s.length() > 10) {
                           lastTenCharContact = s.substring(s.length() - 10);
                       } else {
                           lastTenCharContact = s;
                       }
                       // String substring = s.substring(Math.max(s.length() - 10, 0));
                       Log.d(TAG, "getContactsDetails: " + lastTenCharContact);
                       String image_uri = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.PHOTO_URI));
                       ContactString.add(lastTenCharContact);

                       DeviceContact contactModel = new DeviceContact(Name.toUpperCase(), lastTenCharContact, image_uri);

                       contactModelsList.add(contactModel);
                         mobileNoSet.add(number);

                       Log.d(TAG, "Name : " + Name + ", Number : " + number + ", Photo : " + image_uri);}
                   }
                   hideLoader();
                   AllContactsyncapiCall();

               } else {
                   tvNoContact.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
               }
           }    }
```

Answer (score 0):

for remove duplicate Number just make hashset before your loop:

```
HashSet<String> mobileNoSet = new HashSet<String>();
```

Now when you put contact in model use below code:

```
if (!mobileNoSet.contains(number)){

                   String s = number.replaceAll("\\W", "");
                   String lastTenCharContact = null;
                   if (s != null && s.length() > 10) {
                       lastTenCharContact = s.substring(s.length() - 10);
                   } else {
                       lastTenCharContact = s;
                   }
                   // String substring = s.substring(Math.max(s.length() - 10, 0));
                   Log.d(TAG, "getContactsDetails: " + lastTenCharContact);
                   String image_uri = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.PHOTO_URI));
                   ContactString.add(lastTenCharContact);

                   DeviceContact contactModel = new DeviceContact(Name.toUpperCase(), lastTenCharContact, image_uri);
                   contactModelsList.add(contactModel);
                   mobileNoSet.add(number);
        }
```

Comment: i used it in my app and it is working perfectly. mobileNoSet  hashSet store numbers and if set contais number from cursor then it will not allow to add it in  DeviceContact contactModel . post your newer code

Comment: you getting duplicate entry because you are creating new Hashset in every loop. now move this line HashSet<String> mobileNoSet = new HashSet<String>();  after tvNoContact.setVisibility(View.GONE);

Comment: thanx..it working but when my device sync with whatsapp or any other account than i m getting same issue.

Comment: how you sync with other account?

Comment: sync contact automatically from device if that contact register with that app.so if we see in device that time it display sync with whatsapp,mobiquick etc.

Comment: but it is responsibility of that specific app. what is relation between your contact array and that app?

Comment: it is right but i don't understand how same contact number come if number sync with other app.if u get any solution than good.

Comment: means your defalut contact app shows duplicate number. like 12345 as main number, 12345 as whatsapp, 12345 as viber app, right?

Comment: you can not change default contact app behaviour. you can fetch unique contacts from device and send it to your server.

Comment: yes,but for that i need solution.i tried out many solution but not sucess.

Comment: what is your exact requirement?

Comment: My contact app shows duplicate number. like 12345 as main number, 12345 as whatsapp, 12345 as viber app. i need to display only one time if same contact.

Comment: I analyzed contact app, u can manually UnLink other numbers. so there will be 12345 number 3 times. now you can hide that other 2 number from display. I think there will be programmatically way  to doing this.

Comment: ok.we can not unlink from contact book manuaally,because all user not do that.if u getting solution for programatically give me.thanx.

Comment: hii..@divyesh patel. i m useing this code than again i get duplicate number.can u help me.

Comment: i posted pls check.

Comment: i posted as answer divyesh

Answer (score 0):

This is new code in which i m getting duplicate number :-

```
  private void getContactsDetails() {
    // showLoader();
    Cursor phones = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null, null/*selection + " AND " + ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER + "=1"*/, null, "UPPER(" + ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME + ") ASC");
    ContactString = new ArrayList<>();
    nameString = new ArrayList<>();

    if (phones != null) {

        if (phones.getCount() > 0) {
            tvNoContact.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            HashSet<String> mobileNoSet = new HashSet<String>();
            while (phones.moveToNext()) {
                String Name = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME));
                String number = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));

                if (!mobileNoSet.contains(number)) {
                    //  String s = number.replaceAll("\\W", "");

                    String s = number.replaceAll("[^[+]\\d]", "");

                    String lastTenCharContact = null;
                    lastTenCharContact = s;
                /*if (s != null && s.length() > 10) {
                    lastTenCharContact = s.substring(s.length() - 10);
                } else {
                    lastTenCharContact = s;
                }*/
                    // String substring = s.substring(Math.max(s.length() - 10, 0));
                    Log.d(TAG, "getContactsDetails: " + lastTenCharContact);
                    String image_uri = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.PHOTO_URI));
                    ContactString.add(lastTenCharContact);
                    // nameString.add(Name);
                    contactModel = new DeviceContact(Name.toUpperCase(), lastTenCharContact, image_uri);
                    contactModelsList.add(contactModel);
                    mobileNoSet.add(number);
                    Log.d(TAG, "Name : " + Name + ", Number : " + number + ", Photo : " + image_uri);
                }
            }
            //     hideLoader();
            AllContactsyncapiCall();

        } else {
            tvNoContact.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: i want to save distinct contact number in  contactModel = new DeviceContact(Name.toUpperCase(), lastTenCharContact, image_uri);
                    contactModelsList.add(contactModel);

Comment: Your code looks good, have you check log if same number is printed inside hashset check method?

Comment: Try to place mobileNoset.add(number) right after if(!mobileNoSet.contains(number)) condition

Comment: Not working this solution :-
Try to place mobileNoset.add(number) right after if(!mobileNoSet.contains(number)) condition

Comment: Does Log shows duplocate number in while loop? And post log mobileNoSet.size() after loop complete.